# Metadata Navigation for list works until added to a page

Tags: sharepoint-server, metadata-navigation

I have a list to which I've enabled Metadata Navigation.  It works fine when I access the list directly.  However, when I add the list to a page as a web app, I no longer see the navigation panel.

I'm using SharePoint 2013.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design.

When you enable Metadata Navigation for a list/library, you will see this navigation only when you are in this list/library.

If you add the list/library to a page as a web part, it will not display the corresponding Metadata Navigation.

Comment: Thanks.  I do find it odd that they strongly link the two like that.  I'll find an alternate approach.
Cheers!